# EOF while reading packet

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, cyberduck

I am trying to connect via SFTP to my DigitalOcean VPS using username/password authentication, but cyberduck gives me the following error when doing so:

```
Interoperability failure
EOF while reading packet. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.
```

Connecting to my server via the macos terminal works fine: `$ ssh 'user@domain'`

What causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

is because you need update your password in the Terminal window.

*open Digital ocean panel
 * go to access tab
 * open Console access
 * login with root access
 * put your password ( Digital Ocean send you that by Email )
 * Put your new password ( YES Create a new password )

now you can login with Cyberduck.